# ORMLite where clausule in String Array

Tags: android, arrays, where-clause, ormlite

I use ormlite and I have a db with a field:

```
public static final String NAME = "name"; 
@DatabaseField (canBeNull = false, dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE, columnName = NAME)
private String[] name = new String[2];
```

And I would like to get all elements that name[0] and name[1] are "car". I try to add a where clausule like:

```
NAMEDB nameDB = null;
Dao<NAMEDB, Integer> daoName = this.getHelper().getDao(NAMEDB.class);
QueryBuilder<NAMEDB, Integer> queryName = daoName.queryBuilder();
Where<NAMEDB, Integer> where = queryName.where();
where.in(nameDb.NAME, "car");
```

But it doesn't work because it's an array string.

I have other fields:

```
public static final String MARK = "mark";

@DatabaseField (canBeNull = false, foreign = true, index = true, columnName = MARK)
private String mark = null;
```

And I can do this:

```
whereArticulo.in(nameDB.MARK, "aaa");
```

How can I solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not good with annotations or anything. But do you use a third party library, or a custom made ORM that supports this? If so you should mention it in your question. If it's a library specific issue.. just a tip. Cause atleast I, and probably others won't know the internal structure of the "in" method.

Comment: Sorry.  It's my first time that i write here. I've changed my question and I've added more code and information. Thanks

Comment: It's no problem, i won't be able to help you, but I hope others will be able to, according to the changes. :) if possible add ormlite(instead of sqlite3 of u cant add more) as a tag and perhaps add it to the title too.

Comment: According to the documentation, the in method does not accept an array, but it will accept a collection. Convert/change the array into a List object. like List<String> and try it again. If it doesn't work, use the iteratable. like Iterator<String> iter = listObjName.iterator();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does *not* support querying fields that are the type `SERIALIZABLE`.   It is storing the array as a serialized `byte[]` so you cannot query against the values with an `IN` query like:

```
where.in(nameDb.NAME, "car");
```

ORMLite does support foreign collections but you have to set it up yourself with another class holding the names.  See the documentation with sample code:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that a third option to store a string array (`String[] someStringArray[]`) in the database using `Ormlite` would be to define a data persister class that converts the string array to a single delimited string upon storage into the database and back again to a string array after taking it out of the database.

E.g., persister class would convert `["John Doe", "Joe Smith"]` to `"John Doe | Joe Smith"` for database storage (using whatever delimiter character makes sense for your data) and converts back the other way when taking the data out of the database.

Any thoughts on this approach versus using Serializable or a foreign collection?  Anyone tried this?

I just wrote my first persister class and it was pretty easy. I haven't been able to identify through web search or StackOverflow search that anyone has tried this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As ronbo4610 suggested, it is a good idea to use a custom data persister in this case, to store the array as a string in the database separated by some kind of delimiter. You can then search the string in your WHERE clause just as you would any other string. (For example, using the LIKE operator)

I have implemented such a data persister. In order to use it, you must add the following annotation above your String[] object in your persisted class:

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = ArrayPersister.class)
```

In addition, you must create a new class called "ArrayPersister" with the following code:

```
import com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.SqlType;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.types.StringType;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ArrayPersister extends StringType {
    private static final String delimiter = ",";
    private static final ArrayPersister singleTon = new ArrayPersister();

    private ArrayPersister() {
        super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[]{ String[].class });
    }

    public static ArrayPersister getSingleton() {
        return singleTon;
    }

    @Override
    public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object javaObject) {
        String[] array = (String[]) javaObject;

        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return StringUtils.join(array, delimiter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos) {
        String string = (String)sqlArg;

        if (string == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return string.split(delimiter);
        }
    }
}
```